# How to easily read IPMI data from a HP ML110 G4 server?

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, ipmi

is there a windows application to read the IPMI data on my HP ML110 G4 server? I need to monitor the temperature levels.

I can view raw IPMI data in the BIOS, but this is no use while the server is running!

Comment: What operating system are you using? Be specific.

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2!

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky...

Older 100-series ProLiant servers lacked the management features of the higher-end 300-series. Much of this will depend on what hardware components you have installed in the server. There's no [**ProLiant Support Pack**](http://www.hp.com/servers/psp) or health agent software for the ML110 G4. Also, do you have the [Lights-Out LO100i management card](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/remotemgmt/lightsout100i-advanced/index.html) installed/configured? That's the easiest approach.

[The full set of software for Windows Server 2003 32-bit is here.](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=3279681&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=swEnvOID%253D1005%257CswLang%253D%257Caction%253DlistDriver&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) (This server model predates Windows Server 2008!)

---

But my take on this is: These servers are pretty resilient. What is wrong in your environment where you need to specifically monitor temperature? *And if you notice that there is something wrong with temperatures, **what can you do about it?*** - What is the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Nope, no Lights Out Card. Ideally I would be getting another server, but the rack mounted HP's take up so much space!

It's running in a room without aircon, and I was a tad worried about the temp. It would also be nice to have access to the built in monitoring.

Comment: You really don't need to monitor temperature. If you're worried about the room, don't put the server there.

Answer (score -1):

A quick glance at the documentation, or a web search would have lead you to [HP Systems Insight Manager](http://h18013.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/hpsim/index.html?jumpid=go/hpsim), which is what you want to use for this.

Comment: I've tried installing this but it throws up "SQL server 2008 express R2 installation failed with exit code: -206857830". Someone said I would need a version of the software compatible with my server, but I can't find one!